# Docker on windows server 2022, problems running ELK stack

Tags: docker, logstash, elk

I have installed Docker on a windows 2022 server following a description for 2019 server. Docker seems to be running linux containers ok.
However when I try and get the ELK stack up and running with docker-compose i get the following error everytime the logstash is going to be build:

```
failed to register layer: failed sending to tar2vhd for C:\ProgramData\docker\lcow\151517b759d9318e1e0d7880b96d99471b9f0635c1586ee2ebda888302e84e1b\layer.vhd: opengcs: copyWithTimeout: error reading: 'open \tmp\3ce497f4af24bcd3fbd77feb0f34593533b66a2a52a5391d86ca114a04152f50-mount\usr\local\bin\docker-entrypoint: The system cannot find the path specified.' after 0 bytes (stdin of tar2vhd for generating C:\ProgramData\docker\lcow\151517b759d9318e1e0d7880b96d99471b9f0635c1586ee2ebda888302e84e1b\layer.vhd) 
ERROR: Service 'logstash' failed to build : Build failed
```

I have tried different version, this version is 17.15.1 and I just seem to run into the same problem every time.
Does anybody have any suggestions ?